# How to create a task on windows using powershell and specified trigger

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to create a task on windows taskscreduler using the powershell but without success. The script I need to create based GUI description:

"At 08:00 every day -After triggered, repeat every 02:00:00 for a duration of 12 hours"

I already found the solution using multiple trigger that could work in this situation:

`-Trigger @(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 8am; New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 10am; New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 12pm; New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 2pm; New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 4pm; New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 6pm; New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 8pm)`

But the problem is obvious....in the future if I need a task that run more times a day this script will become a monster.
So, someone knows a better solution for that?

Comment: `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Hours 2) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Hours 12) -At 8:00`  Could also try using the Repetition interval/duration parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: Scheduled Task with Daily Trigger and Repetition Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108886/powershell-scheduled-task-with-daily-trigger-and-repetition-interval)

Comment: @Grok42 Don't work, you can't use "-Daily" and "-RepetitionInterval" together. 
That's the sintax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: @PatrickMcvay the solution selected to that another question don't seems to be a "good solution" as well, I was hoping that after some time someone had a inline solution, more like the Grok42 answer (but sadly dosn't work that way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigge) doesn't allow you to combine `-RepetitionInterval` and `-RepetitionDuration` with `-Daily`, as you've discovered, you can use *multiple* triggers, which you can create *algorithmically*:

```bash
Register-ScheduledTask ... `
  -Trigger (0..6).ForEach({ New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At "$(8+2*$_):00" })
```

Note:

- These multiple triggers are also reflected in the Task Scheduler GUI (`taskschd.msc`) as such:

  - [image: Task Scheduler screenshot]
- The underlying APIs *are* capable of representing this logic in a *single* trigger, as the description in your question ("At 08:00 every day -After triggered, repeat every 02:00:00 for a duration of 12 hours") demonstrates.
- It is therefore unfortunate, that a purely *syntactic* restriction in `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` limits access to some task-scheduler API features.

  - [This related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108886/powershell-scheduled-task-with-daily-trigger-and-repetition-interval) offers *workarounds* that *do* allow use of a single trigger, but these workarounds are more verbose and therefore impractical for inline solutions.

Comment: Perfect mklement0! That's a more complex solution but for sure the best solution I ever found. Really thanks!